# WordPress PHP - How do I sort category/archive results by a specific "meta_key" value?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, meta-tags

I previously made a post here:  [How do I sort by a custom field without manually creating a new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664814/how-do-i-sort-by-a-custom-field-without-manually-creating-a-new-page)

However, I believe I asked the wrong question (and I may still be asking the wrong question).  Actually think I may need a complex query that will display posts ordered by a meta value.   The site is using a theme called "AgentPress".  I believe passing params via the URL bar may be too simplistic for what I need.

Honestly I like the way the current category pages display (formatting, etc.), I simply need to "short-circuit" the process so that any category/archive page is sorted by the meta_key for the "property price" as opposed to the date of entry.  If there is a simple, more "WordPress-y" mechanism for doing this, I'm all ears. Please be explicit about where to place the code, etc.

FYI, at this point it's clear that passing "order=ASC" and "order=DESC" in the URL works.  However, it seems that nothing I do with "meta_key" or anything related has *any* effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a filter on `pre_get_posts` hook.

Put this code in `functions.php` (in your theme dir) :

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_hook' );

function pre_get_posts_hook($wp_query) {
    if (is_category() || is_archive())
    {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        return $wp_query;
    }
}
```

You can use `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num` (available with v2.8), but I assume that price is a numeric value.

Comment: Although I have yet to test it, this is EXACTLY the kind of thing I need.  Only problem is, the META values aren't working.  It simply orders ASC and DESC by date, not the 'price' meta key.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with `$wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'property price' );`

Comment: Is it possible to display posts that don't have a value for the custom field after the ordered posts? Perhaps just displaying them by the default `orderby=date`.

Comment: This made a real mess of things for me. It changed way too much unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you find you lose your navigation menu, I updated @soju's answer as follows:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_hook' );

function pre_get_posts_hook($wp_query) {
    if ( is_archive() && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) { //edited this line
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        return $wp_query;
    }
}
```

Then the filter won't affect your nav menu

Comment: this helped me a lot, although your code through errors out.  $wp_query -> is_main-query() should be : && $wp_query->is_main_query()

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find this functionality under a class called PostsOrderedByMetaQuery that extends WP_Query and accepts new arguments 'orderby_meta_key' and 'orderby_order'

```
class PostsOrderedByMetaQuery extends WP_Query {
var $posts_ordered_by_meta = true;
var $orderby_order = 'ASC';
var $orderby_meta_key;
function __construct($args=array()) {

add_filter('posts_join',array(&$this,'posts_join'),10,2);
add_filter('posts_orderby',array(&$this,'posts_orderby'),10,2);
$this->posts_ordered_by_meta = true;
$this->orderby_meta_key = $args['orderby_meta_key'];
unset($args['orderby_meta_key']);
if (!empty($args['orderby_order'])) {
  $this->orderby_order = $args['orderby_order'];
  unset($args['orderby_order']);
}
parent::query($args);
}
function posts_join($join,$query) {
if (isset($query->posts_ordered_by_meta)) {
  global $wpdb;
  $join .=<<<SQL
 INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} postmeta_price ON postmeta_price.post_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
   AND postmeta_price.meta_key='{$this->orderby_meta_key}'
SQL;
}
return $join;
}
function posts_orderby($orderby,$query) {
if (isset($query->posts_ordered_by_meta)) {
  global $wpdb;
  $orderby = "postmeta_price.meta_value {$this->orderby_order}";
 }
return $orderby;
 }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
  $thirtydays = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+30 days'));
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

  $query = new PostsOrderedByMetaQuery(array
  (
  'post_type' => array('post', 'real-estate'),
  'meta_key' => 'Time Available',
  'meta_compare' => '<=',
  'meta_value' => $thirtydays,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'orderby_meta_key' => 'Price',
  'orderby_order'    => 'DESC',
   ));

  foreach($query->posts as $post) 
  {
      echo " {$post->post_title}\n";
  }
```

You can copy the PostsOrderedByMetaQuery class to your theme's functions.php file, or you can use it within a .php file of a plugin you may be writing.

Comment: @humble_coder: Does that answer help?? Do you have any other Comments or questions?

Comment: Well, my initial goal is/was to short-circuit the process and use the query with the existing template(s).  I really like the formatting and an not interested in re-writing or managing it for such a "quick" change.  However, with the way this custom theme is set up, I'm not sure that is a viable option.  WP has too many globals to track down.  Unless you have any additional suggestions, I guess that is it.  I'll wait just a bit longer for a "better" answer and award the points in the next 48 hours.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @humble_coder: Working with the existing template is something that you have to customize yourself because it's different for every theme. Have you tried contacting the maker of the theme at http://www.studiopress.com/contact? Their website says that they offer unlimited support. Maybe you could send them this code and ask them to integrate it into their theme as an option under the control panel for you since you did pay for the theme.

Comment: Yup already did that.  They were very friendly.  However, they said it was out of their realm.  I have one more recourse, which is to directly contact one of their devs, I was warned that my request might involved development costs.  I'm quite competent with PHP, I'm just unsure of the structure of WP and this particular theme.